# Unfamiliar errors

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, ceil

I'm writing a program dealing with threads that I've almost got working completely. Unfortunately, I'm hitting an error (repeated 4 times) who's syntax I'm not familiar with. Here's a quick snip-it of my compile commands, and the errors that follow:

```
 gcc -o threads threads.cpp -pthread<br>
/tmp/ccy8maS0.o: In function `tenPercentA()':
threads.cpp:(.text+0xde): undefined reference to `ceil'
/tmp/ccy8maS0.o: In function `tenPercentB()':
threads.cpp:(.text+0x1c6): undefined reference to `ceil'
/tmp/ccy8maS0.o: In function `fiftPercentC()':
threads.cpp:(.text+0x2ae): undefined reference to `ceil'
/tmp/ccy8maS0.o: In function `fiftPercentD()':
threads.cpp:(.text+0x396): undefined reference to `ceil'
/tmp/ccy8maS0.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've already included the math.h library in my program, and I'm using the correct syntax for the call:

```
ceil(tempA);
```

Where tempA is a double holding the value I need to be rounded up.
Any suggestions? I've tried Google'ing these errors but, like most errors, it's hard to find specific examples with the same pattern as yours.
EDIT: I've solved all of the ceil related errors (using -lm on the command line) however the last error still remains, and I have no idea what it means, or how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring the undefined reference to `ceil()`:

You seem to be missing to link against `libm`.

Adding the option `-lm` to your call to `gcc` should solve this problem.

---

`#include`ing `math.h` is for the compiler to get to know `ceil()`'s defintion. The linker then later needs to know where `ceil()`'s implementation actually resides, namely in `libm`.

Comment: Yeah, just figured that out! Thank you :)
I've also figured out what was causing the last error, AKA compiling with gcc vs. g++ (I saved the file in the wrong extension)